# How can you create a reactive & non-reactive Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm struggling with an odd problem. As soon as a document gets updated with a certain attribute, it no longer matches the publish query. Meteor rips it out of the DOM and removes it from the clientside collection.

I need the listings to stay in place so the user can still go back and undo their choice. However I need them *to not show up* on the next page load.

I can simulate what i'm after if I send the entire collection to the client and then make reactive false if it returns more than 0 results. On refresh only listings that have not been chosen show up. Obviously this is not good for performance.

My publish query basically just filters out the correct type of listing and also pulls
in listings that the user hasn't chose like/dislike. It was incrementing the limit but I couldn't make
it work without losing the previously chosen listings

```
Meteor.publish('listings', function(type, limit, ulid) {
  var query, options;

  query = {
    type:      type,
    completed: true,
    'public':  true
  };

  options = {
    sort:  {title: 1},
    limit: 1000        // debugging, should be param
  };

  // if user is logged in, get their listing id
  if (ulid) {
    query.likedBy    = { $ne: ulid };
    query.dislikedBy = { $ne: ulid };
  }

  return Listings.find(query, options);
});


// client, simulates the effect I need, but doesn't work if you increase limit

Template.listings.helpers({
  listings: function() {
    var listType, results;

    listType = Session.get('listingType');

    results = Listings.find({type: listType }, {reactive: false}).fetch();

    // prevents race condition where sometimes listings come through anyway
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      var ul = Session.get('userListing')._id;
      results.likedBy =    { $ne: ul };
      results.dislikedBy = { $ne: ul };
    }

    // if results haven't arrived fetch again with reactivity
    if (!results.length) {
      results = Listings.find({ type: listType }).fetch();
    }

    // append a 'no listings avail.' card to the end of results
    // If no results are found, user only sees not found card
    results.push({type: 'empty'});
    return results;
  }
});
```

For visual, each document is displayed one at a time and the user swipes right
to get new listings and left to go back and see/undo old one.

```
-----------------------
|                     |
| |-----------------| |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |    listing #1   | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |-----------------| |
|                     |
-----------------------
```

Comment: This is un-related to the question but I noticed in the code you supplied your helper is using find().fetch() and returning the resulting array. I assume you are using an {{#each listings}} block in your template to render each item. If you can get around the need to push the empty 'no items card' it would be much better to return the Collection cursor that results from the find rather than fetching the array and returning the array. When you give the {{#each }} block a collection cursor Meteor is much smarter about re-rendering only the items that change rather than every item in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now that I think of it, I should be able to do this in the template by adding a node after the `each` block. This way the swipe plugin still has an extra on the end and Meteor won't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. You're not really looking to make the template reactive and non-reactive, but find a way to keep certain documents published during a user "session" even though a field has changed which would normally cause the document to be un-published.

One solution that came to mind would be to have a second publication that keeps those documents that have been liked or disliked published if the like or dislike was added during the current session. Two publications can publish from the same Collection and the result is that the Collection on the client is the union of these two publications.

So when a user clicks "like" or "dislike" you would add the _id of that document to a session variable which is an array of documents to keep published. Using a subscription within a deps.autorun you could reactively send this list of _ids to the server and tell it to publish those documents along side your normal publication.

One issue would be the order of the documents in the collection changing as they are taken out of one subscription/publication and put into another. You might need use a sort on the 
Listings.find() inside your helper to keep the order from changing. Also depending on latency the list might still "flicker" as the document is removed from one publication and added to another.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
//Server side publish
Meteor.publish('listingsForSession', function(listingIds) {
check(listingIds, [String]);
  if(listingIds.length > 0){
      return Listings.find({_id: {$in: listingIds}});
  }
});

//Client side subscription
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if(Meteor.userId()){
        Meteor.subscribe("listingsForSession", Session.get("listingIdsToKeep")); 
    }     
});

//Click handler to keep track of documents that have been liked/disliked
Template.listings.events({
    'click .like, click .dislike': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var listingId = $(event.currentTarget).data("id"); //Or however you get the document _id
        var listingIdsToKeep = Session.get("listingIdsToKeep");
        listingIdsToKeep.push(listingId);
        Session.set('listingIdsToKeep', listingIdsToKeep);
    }
});
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it could work.

Comment: Awesome! This looks promising. I'll try this when I wake up. The other thing I tried and failed was creating a separate array in Session. Basically I would watch/autorun the query and then merge the old/new data into a session var. That session var then fed into the template. However I had horrible problems keeping it updated.

Comment: This worked great! The key to keeping the order and prevent flickering was inserting the id into the Session array *before* making a like/dislike. In fact in the listings controller (instead of ui event) I had to wrap a setTimeout with 0 around the Meteor like methods to make it wait. Brilliant, thanks @Dysko !